# A basic question on probability theory

Tags: probability-theory

I see in the first chapter of Billingsley's book  that the mathematical properties of the sequence of digits in the binary expansion (non-terminating)  of $\omega$ where $\omega \in [0,1]$ mirror the properties to be expected of a coin-tossing process that continues forever. But only a proof for finite case is given. How to prove the infinite case ?

Answer (score 1):

> How to prove the infinite case ?

Nothing to do here: the distribution of the infinite process is determined by the collection of its finite marginal distributions. Thus, if the latter coincide, the former coincide.

Comment: I have not understood the use of the statement : "the mathematical properties of the sequence of digits in the binary expansion (non-terminating)  of $\omega$ where $\omega \in [0,1]$ mirror the properties to be expected of a coin-tossing process that continues forever". What is the meaning of this claim ?

Comment: That the sequence made of the $n$ first digits is uniformly distributed in the corresponding set of size $2^n$, for every $n$.

Comment: No, what I meant is that is there any motivation behind showing the equivalence of the problems involving an infinitely repeated operation and those involving an infinitely fine operation in a broad sense ?

Comment: Sure, to put all the finite random sequences in a unique model, which is (esthetically pleasing and) necessary if one wants to consider *almost sure limits*.

Comment: Can you elaborate it in detail ?

Comment: What do you want me to "elaborate"? That, to consider the almost sure limit of a sequence of random variables, these must be defined on a common probability space? Seems obvious, doesn't it?